# cannot load such file -- multi_json (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rswag

After successfully doing bundle when I run this command to generate rswag helper "rails g rswag:install" produces the error

```
cannot load such file -- multi_json (LoadError)
```

I have tried to delete and create the project again and again, also after running this command no commands work for anything.

```
 rswag_app git:(master) ✗ rails s
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- multi_json (LoadError)
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:88:in `register'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/json-schema-2.8.1/lib/json-schema.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you add the output of the command or logs, versions. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: rswag_app git:(master) ✗ rails s
/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- multi_json (LoadError)
 from /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 from /Us

Comment: It seems `rails` is not finding the gem `multi_json`. Please verify if you have it installed with `gem list multi_json` or try installing it manually with `gem install multi_json`. Please add the output of those commands to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.